# Yii2 Codeception Functional tests - Click on OK button of confirm dialog

Tags: yii2, functional-testing, codeception

I'm a newer in Yii2 and programming tests.
I'm using Codeception for testing.

**Summary**:
In one of my tests I have to click on OK button of a confirm dialog. In order to do this, I have tried:
$I->click('OK');
$I->acceptPopup();
Neither of them work.

**Details**:
I'm using ActiveRecord to deal with a table of products ('productos'), and I used Gii to generate scripts.

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "productos".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $codigo
 * @property string $descripcion
 * @property double $cantidad
 * @property double $precio
 * @property string $fefecto
 *
 * @property DetallesPedido[] $detallesPedidos
 */
class Productos extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'productos';
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['codigo', 'descripcion', 'precio', 'fefecto'], 'required'],
        [['cantidad', 'precio'], 'number'],
        [['fefecto'], 'date', 'format'=>'yyyy-M-d'],
        [['fefecto'], 'safe'],
        [['codigo'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
        [['descripcion'], 'string', 'max' => 60],
    ];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'codigo' => 'Codigo',
        'descripcion' => 'Descripcion',
        'cantidad' => 'Cantidad',
        'precio' => 'Precio',
        'fefecto' => 'Fecha Alta',
    ];
}
}
```

The script for the view asociated to Productos.php is:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Productos */

    $this->title = $model->id . ' - ' . $model->codigo;
    $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Productos', 'url' => ['index']];
    $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="productos-view">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Update', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], [
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'data' => [
                'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
                'method' => 'post',
            ],
        ]) ?>
    </p>

    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'codigo',
            'descripcion',
            'cantidad',
            'precio',
            'fefecto',
        ],
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

The script for functional test:

```
<?php

use app\models\Productos;

class ProductosCest
{
public function _before(\FunctionalTester $I)
{
    //Deleting all products from database
    Productos::deleteAll();

    $I->amLoggedInAs(100);//Logarse
    $I->amOnRoute('productos/index');

    // Loading product on database
    $I->haveRecord(Productos::className(), [
        'id' => 1,
        'codigo' => 'PA01',
        'descripcion' => 'Paleta de acero triangular de 20 cm',
        'cantidad' => 1,
        'precio' => 10.53,
        'fefecto' => '2017-03-12',
    ]);
}

public function _after(\FunctionalTester $I)
{
    $I->click(['class' => 'btn-link']);//Logout

    //Deleting all products from database
    Productos::deleteAll();

}

public function deleteProducto(\FunctionalTester $I)
{
    $I->amGoingTo('delete a product');
    $I->amOnRoute('productos/delete', ['id' => 1]); //Click delete button from id=1

    //Pulsar el botón Aceptar
    /*
    $I->performOn('.confirm', \Codeception\Util\ActionSequence::build()
    ->see('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')
    ->click('Aceptar')
    );
    */
    $I->acceptPopup();

    $I->expect('be in the index product view');
    $I->see('Productos', 'h1');

    $I->expect('the product is not in the index product view');
    $I->dontSee('Paleta de acero triangular de 20 cm');

}

}
```

**When I run tests, I get:**

There was 1 failure:

---

1) ProductosCest: Delete producto
 Test  tests/functional/ProductosCest.php:deleteProducto
 Step  Click {"class":"btn-link"}
 Fail  Link or Button by name or CSS or XPath element with class 'btn-link' was not found.

Scenario Steps:

6. $I->click({"class":"btn-link"}) at tests/functional/ProductosCest.php:28
7. $I->amOnRoute("productos/delete",{"id":1}) at tests/functional/ProductosCest.php:132
8. // I am going to delete a product
9. $I->haveRecord("app\models\Productos",{"id":1,"codigo":"PA01","descripc...}) at tests/functional/ProductosCest.php:17
10. $I->amOnRoute("productos/index") at tests/functional/ProductosCest.php:13
11. $I->amLoggedInAs(100) at tests/functional/ProductosCest.php:12

As you can see, there is a problem in line:
    $I->acceptPopup();
because message 'be in the index product view' does not appear in the test log.

**Screenshots:**
[View products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rcqX.png)

[Confirm Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcQ0M.png)

Answer (score 2):

You use [Yii2](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Yii2) module in functional tests, right?
This module does not execute javascript code, so you won't get confirmation dialog.

In order to test confirmation dialog, you must use [WebDriver](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver) module, which is used in `acceptance` suite usually.

[acceptPopup](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#acceptPopup) method only works with native popup windows, as created by window.alert, window.confirm or window.prompt.
If you use a modal window (it looks like you do), you must use [click](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#click) method to click it.